# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined for Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

<!-- update the version number as needed -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.6.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.6.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
<script defer>
  var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: 'main.html',
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
    // Privacy policy url/callback.
    privacyPolicyUrl: function() {
      window.location.assign('<your-privacy-policy-url>');
    }
  };
  var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
  ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
</script>
```

When I open up the page in my browser, I get the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`. I'm not sure how to rectify this problem. I'm using the reserved hosting urls to download the Firebase JS SDK. My understanding is that the config variable and the `initializeApp()` method that you see in other posts about the problem are not needed, right? I'm really not sure what's going on. I tried inserting the scripts in the body and head of the document. I even tried using a separate js file inserted at the bottom of the body element..

An Update.

I placed the code in the sign in script at the bottom of the body and combined it with some code that checks the auth state. It looks like this

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {console.log("user: " + user);});
    // firebase.database().ref('/path/to/ref').on('value', snapshot => { });
    // firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(() => { });
    // firebase.storage().ref('/path/to/ref').getDownloadURL().then(() => { });
  });
  var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: 'main.html',
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ],
    tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>',
    // Privacy policy url/callback.
    privacyPolicyUrl: function() {
      window.location.assign('<your-privacy-policy-url>');
    }
  };
  var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
  ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
</script>
```

The `console.log("user: " + user)` statement prints user: null, suggesting the `firebase` object in the `addEventListner()` is defined. Yet, the `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,` line throws the same error as it did before. why?

Comment: What line of code in which file causes the error? Do you get any 404's for any of the script file inclusions? Is there a reason you're deferring from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-hosting-urls)?

Comment: the `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,` line @Phil. no 404s mentioned in the console log. When I set up firebase hosting, it generated a index.html document with all the script files set up that way (except for the one I added).

Comment: just tried to open the init.js file (via cmd click) and I got an error message stating `Unable to read file '/__/firebase/init.js' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/__/firebase/init.js')`

Comment: I wasn't able to see the init.js file until I deployed the site.

Comment: the init.js file does use the `initializeApp()` function

Comment: I would suggest you start by following the documentation exactly as it appears. First thing to do is remove all those `defer` attributes. Once you get it working, then start optimising your script loading

Comment: @Phil, I posted an update after finding out something interesting. Would moving the scripts around change the behavior where `firebase` is defined in one area of the script but not the other? As of right now, I'm thinking I shouldn't be using firebaseUI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not resolve the problem. In the end I choose not to use FirebaseUI and created my own sign in flow instead.